# Why button is overlapping with div?

Tags: html, css

I have a main wrapper div with a content div and a button. The button is supposed to go underneath the content div but for some reason it's overlapping with it.

The content div has css:

```
#groupMembers {
    position: absolute;
    height: 50%;
    width: 90%;
    left: 5%;
    overflow: scroll;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

and the button has:

```
button {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 70%;
    left: 15%;
}
```

I thought since they're both inline-block that they wouldn't overlap, but for some reason they are. I made a JsFiddle to show: http://jsfiddle.net/b5hp6boz/

Can anybody help me get the button to display beneath the content div?

Comment: everything absolutely positioned, use relative positioning for elements to remain relative to each other.

Comment: It would also help get answers if you paired down the markup to the *minimal* code necessary. Especially since all classes and ID are just numeric.

Comment: Absolute positioning is a **very** poor method of laying out webpages. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options. Check out [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Comment: Here's what happens when you merely replace the **36** absolute positions with `relative` http://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/b5hp6boz/1/ -- seems easily adjusted from here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Remove** the (extensive) use of absolute positioning.... Change it to `position: relative;` if necessary. But on many elements even that is not necessary.

Move the button div up to under the `<h4>add members</h4>` in the HTML where you appear to want it.

Then adjust margins for `#DIV_05` and the button.

## [Fiddle Update](http://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/b5hp6boz/2/)  or [Fiddle Update 2](http://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/b5hp6boz/3/)

<sub>(Note I merely performed a search to change `absolute` to `relative` in your CSS, then adjusted from there.)</sub>

By using absolute positioning so extensively you were *forcing* elements into unnatural positions. Then when it wasn't working out.. you are left wondering why. Let things fall where they naturally want to fall. Change the **HTML** for overall render order, don't force things with absolute positioning.

Use of absolute position is most commonly used to adjust z-index and make elements not alter positioning of other elements. (like a global float of sorts) It should not be the fall back for positioning *everything* in any layout.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is that you have given the `#DIV_5` the following CSS:

```
position: absolute;
```

By giving a HTML element an absolute position it is removed from the normal rendering process by not obtaining any space in the document. That means it is not affecting the position of the following `BUTTON_105` element. That's why the button is positioned right underneath the `H4_4` element (which is the first element not having an absolute position).

To fix that simply remove the `position: absolute;` declaration for `#DIV_5`. (Btw: You should try not to make heavy use of absolute positioning as it can cause further issues.)

Answer (score -1):

Try giving your div tag a higher z-index value.